# Unable to Scan Barcodes using Mobile Vision

Tags: android, google-vision, android-vision

I've tried to detect these types of barcodes with no dice, I also tried it with the https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision which also couldn't detect the barcode.

Curious why only these types of barcodes are so hard to detect, and if there's a special format to them, IR guns have no problem picking them up.

[Skinny Barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEMsP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Code-128 barcode (which our API does support), though one printed with a fair amount of smudging that may be making it difficult to read. We'll look into it; thanks for the report.

Comment: Thank you, I also have trouble detecting these barcodes with ZXing libraries.